# Как апроксимировать кривую?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, изображения

Добрый день. Встала такая задача: есть массив точек (> 2000) по которым строиться кривая (график), нужно эту кривую отобразить на изображении шириной 800 пикселей. Каким образом можно апроксимировать кривую, чтоб "впихнуть" ее в изображение?

PS: задача стоит в том, чтоб поместить waveform аудиотрека в небольшое изображение, дабы потом не возиться с уменьшением самого изображения.

Comment: Не уверен, что задача имеет корректное решение? Допустим, что ваши значения через одно равны `+1` и `-1`. Как можно корректно ужать это до 800 пикселей?

Answer (score 1):

1. Находите нижнюю левую точку графика
2. Находите верхнюю правую точку графика
3. Вычисляете высоту графика
4. Вычисляете ширину графика
5. Находите коэффициент масштабирования

   ```
   max( graphHeight/imageHeight, graphWidth/imageWidth )
   ```
6. При рисовании делите координату из массива на коэффициент масштабирования

Comment: Окей, а как тогда быть с количеством точек? Вопрос именно в уменьшении количества 2000 точек до колличества 800 точек.

Comment: Вопрос был вот в этом:  

> нужно эту кривую отобразить на изображении шириной 800 пикселей  
А апроксимизация это совершенно другая задача, которая Вам не нужна.  
Или Вы хотите представить множество Ваших точек в виде функции (например)    

    f(x) = ax^n+bx^(n-1)+...+cx
Рисовать и апроксимизировать - разные вещи.

Comment: Вы уверены в том, что количество точек необходимо уменьшить? Если да, то Вы даете неполную информацию по задаче. Это - простой массив или аналитическая функция? Координаты - int или double (float)? Почему нельзя оставить по две точки из каждых пяти? Шаг между точками постоянный?

Comment: Прошу прощения за неточность описания задачи. Я добавил в тело поста. Есть waveform аудиофайла в виде массива точек int. Если представлять в таком виде - выходит файл очень большого размера, что потребует его преобразования дабы избежания проблем с отображением  и памятью (платформа Android).